# RTMP link query

Tags: html, flash, rtmp

I found a link to a live video feed in the html code like this:

```
<embed height="500" width="650" flashvars="file=foxmovies&amp;streamer=rtmp://198.7.58.79/edge&amp;rtmp.subscribe=true&amp;quality=best&amp;controlbar=bottom&amp;rtmp.tunneling=false&amp;frontcolor=#fff&amp;backcolor=#000&amp;stretching=exactfit&amp;autostart=true" wmode="transparent" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" quality="high" src="http://s.zuuk.net/ply.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

I want to know what the actual link to the RTMP stream would be. I'm confused by the "file" and the "edge&amp" and the flashvars.

Thanks

**EDIT1**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("dplayer").setup({
    id: 'dplayer',
       flashplayer: "http://player.ilive.to/player.swf",
    provider: "rtmp",
       streamer: "rtmp://redirect.isearch.to/edge",
    file: "2tag4dzgwof5ma2.flv",
    autostart: "true",
       plugins: {
           "http://player.ilive.to/ova/ova-jw.swf": {
              "ads": {
                 "schedule": [
                     {
                        "position": "pre-roll",
                        "tag": "http://ad4.liverail.com/?LR_PUBLISHER_ID=1912&LR_PARTNERS=718594&LR_SCHEMA=vast2-vpaid&LR_AUTOPLAY=1&LR_CONTENT=6&LR_VERTICALS=[entertainment]&LR_TITLE=[Disney_channel]&LR_VIDEO_ID=[38804]&LR_URL=[http://www.ilive.to/channels/38804/Disney_channel]"
                     }
                 ]
              },

              "debug": {
                  "levels": "fatal, config, vast_template, vpaid, http_calls, playlist, api"
              }
           } 
       },
       height: '100%',
       width: '100%'
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flashvars are key/value pairs that are passed into a Flash movie.

"& amp;" is the divider between key/values (its actually just "&" but presumably has been html-ified somewhere along the line).

So in your case, values are being passed in are:

file = foxmovies

streamer = rtmp://198.7.58.79/edge

rtmp.subscribe = true

quality = best

controlbar = bottom

rtmp.tunneling=false

frontcolor=#fff

backcolor=#000

stretching=exactfit

autostart=true

How the Flash movie is interpreting them to produce a stream URL depends on the code in the Flash movie.

Comment: So using this information, how can I play the stream say on this site: http://www.ideaweb.it/eng/player.cfm

What would I need to type into "Connection Stream" box to stream it?

Comment: So bottom line, there is no way to get the streaming link? See Edit1 in the code above. It's a script inside the html here: http://www.ilive.to/view/38804/watch-live-Disney%20channel-channel-for-free